# cannot select distinct values using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Just want to select distinct values from db using codeigniter but it returns duplicate values. Could you please check what is wrong with my code below:

```
$this->db->distinct('country');
$this->db->where('id',$id);
$query = $this->db->get('table_name');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can try like this?

```
$this->db->distinct();
$this->db->select('country');
```